# Row updation issue in datagrid

Tags: c#

I am updating a row value in thread

```
dataGrid[col,row].value = msg;
```

the above syntax works fine if i use directly but when i use it in a thread it doesnt update the data grid. Later i used a delegate to update the row

```
 if (dataGrid.InvokeRequired)
 {
 //-------------- Delegate Create a differnt thread and end cross reference thread error --
 dGStatusTextDelegate deleg = new dGStatusTextDelegate(dataGridStatusUpdate);
 dataGrid.BeginInvoke(deleg, new object[] { msg,statuscol,row });
 }
 else
 dataGrid[statuscol,row].Value = msg;
```

Still the same responce , no updation in data grid. It works when i dont use thread. Any Help

Comment: add log capability to your application and trace dg value and msg value , and set Control.CheckForIllegalCrossThreadCalls=false;

Comment: Thanx. I debugged it and found the row value guilty :) it changes to 468 automatically. For information 468 are total rows in my table.

Comment: "It works when i dont use thread" , cross thread calling in Constraint Context may be occuired, use semaphore , or in Thread Method Show Log for calling that method.

Answer (score 0):

I used a simple trick to carry the loop value (i) into a temp variable (j). After this it started to work correctly